# Dynamic data on ajax parameter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I use ajax to send the data to php code on submit.
Now, How can I make paramater data on ajax is dynamically from aother condition.
The code looked like this :

```
$('#print-laporan').click(function () {
    var result = $("#hasil-pencarian").clone().end().html();

    if (jenis_laporan === 'bulanan') {
        url_l = "<?= site_url('members/it/p_request/generate_pdf_laporan_bulanan') ?>";
        dataForAjax = ???

    } else if (jenis_laporan === 'mingguan') {

        url_l = "<?= site_url('members/it/p_request/generate_pdf_laporan_mingguan') ?>";
        dataForAjax = ???
    } else {
        url_l = "<?= site_url('members/it/p_request/generate_pdf_laporan_harian') ?>";
        dataForAjax = ???
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: url_l,
        type: 'POST',
        data: ??? // I want to make it dynamic based 'dataForAjax' above,
        success: function () {
            console.log(url_l);
            window.open("<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/tmp/file_laporan.pdf' ?>", "_blank", "top=25, left=250, toolbar=no, width=1000, height=600");

        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });


});
```

Just say

```
if jenis_laporan == 'bulanan' {data : {firstDate : $('some_selector').val(), lastDate : $('some_selector').val(), result: result }
```

AND

```
if jenis_laporan == 'harian' {data : {date : $('some_selector').val(), result: result }} `
```

How can I make it true ?

Comment: I don't understand, the code you have should work, if you assign the data to `dataForAjax` and then assign that variable to `data` inside the `ajax` function, what happens?

Comment: I mean, how to declare the dataForAjax inside the condition ?

Comment: simply pass the variable to data ? `data: dataForAjax,`

Comment: Can I declare like this : dataForAjax = {firstDate : $('some_selector').val(), lastDate : $('some_selector').val(), result: result } . Noted. In condition above $(ajax)

Comment: yes ofcourse you can..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, please explain further if it's not the case.

```
$('#print-laporan').click(function () {
    var result = $("#hasil-pencarian").clone().end().html();

    if (jenis_laporan === 'bulanan') {
        url_l = "<?= site_url('members/it/p_request/generate_pdf_laporan_bulanan') ?>";
        dataForAjax = {
            firstDate: $('some_selector').val(),
            lastDate : $('some_selector').val(),
            result: result
        }
    } else if (jenis_laporan === 'mingguan') {
        url_l = "<?= site_url('members/it/p_request/generate_pdf_laporan_mingguan') ?>";
        dataForAjax = {
            // Whatever you want
        }
    } else {
        url_l = "<?= site_url('members/it/p_request/generate_pdf_laporan_harian') ?>";
        dataForAjax = {
            date : $('some_selector').val(),
            result: result
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: url_l,
        type: 'POST',
        data: dataForAjax,
        success: function () {
            console.log(url_l);
            window.open("<?php echo base_url() . 'assets/tmp/file_laporan.pdf' ?>", "_blank", "top=25, left=250, toolbar=no, width=1000, height=600");
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('Error');
        }
    });
});
```